# Normal Map Baking Random Artifacts On Substance Painter

Tags: export, normal-map

I modeled high poly gas lamp,unwrapped uv map on blender then export to substance painter to bake a normal map. But when i do that i get random artifacts on mesh. I tried up to antialiasing x8,resolution to 2k and tweaked with max frontal and rear distance but these couldn't solve this problem. I have been trying to figure out what cause this for 2 days. Anyone can help me i'll be so glad.
[image: i tried to make space between islands but this couldn't solve too]

[image: artifacts on curvy part and holes on mesh of top part]

[image: also tried match by mesh name (of course i named meshes properly before bake )]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Substance Painter

Comment: Its bake related. I also get this artifacts on blender.

Comment: Do you get these artifacts when you bake in blender? If so, please edit it to show use of blender.